# This bundle is invalid. An unknown device capability value is supplied in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to publish my app to the App Store I get an error which says:

> This bundle is invalid. An unknown device capability value is supplied
>   in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key of the Info.plist. Make
>   certain that the value for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is an array or
>   a dictionary, containing valid values as described in the Information
>   Property List Key Reference.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Plist looks like this:

http://j.mp/V2B8lk

Plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>114.png</string>
        <string>icon.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>114.png</string>
                <string>icon.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>company.appname</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your Info.plist file.

Comment: It's probably easier to delete the entry completely (in the plist editor). See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *Required device capabilities* shouldn't be a *Boolean*. It's supposed to be an array or a dictionary.

I don't know whether you can fix it in the plist editor. If not, you can open the file in a text editor and change it like this:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array></array>
```

**Update**

It's probably best to delete the entry *Required device capabilities* if you don't use it.

Comment: Look at my edit. There's my whole plist in code. What should be edited there?

Comment: Now, when I have edited the plist-code and try to open the plist in Xcode, I just get: "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted".

Comment: Just delete the two lines `<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>` and `<false/>` (next to each other). The rest of the file should stay as you have posted it.